# Ignite lost server node does not reconnect to original Grid

Tags: ignite

While working on the Ignite cluster, I made 4 node Ignite cluster, but due to some network issues one of the server nodes gets disconnected intermittently. While coming back onto network or may be launching another ignite instance from the same machine, does not get appended to the grid. Please suggest some property which allows auto joining of Grid on disconnects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Server nodes can't reconnect back if they were segmented. Ignite doesn't do this because in this case it would have to merge the data which is risky from consistency standpoint. You should completely stop the node and start it again from scratch.

Comment: If we restart the node again from scratch, would ignite re-balance the cache in terms of paritioned cache in some cluster or only the newly written data would be partitioned accordingly.

Comment: Yes, the data will be rebalanced.

Comment: is there any way to implement servers nodes can reconnect automatically after failure  ?

Comment: @Ashok, no, you need to restart. However, you can use native persistence for fast recovery after restart: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/distributed-persistent-store

Comment: how to configure reconectcount ?

Comment: There is no reconnect as I described above. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: @ValentinKulichenko Is there a way for the detached node to know that it has been detached from the main cluster, so that it can restart on its own?

Comment: @Lokesh Yes, client node does reconnect automatically: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/clients-vs-servers#client-reconnect

Comment: @ValentinKulichenko Thanks for replying. What about the server node? How can the server node figure out that it has been detached and segmented, so I can restart it?

Comment: In case of network segmentation you will get two independent clusters and you will have to manually restart one of them. However, there are 3rd party plugins that allow to automate this process. The one provided by GridGain, for example: https://docs.gridgain.com/docs/network-segmentation